# How to use external variable inside promise response of $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

Here is my code

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var url = generate_url(i) ;
    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        var param2 = response.data.param2
        $scope.outputData.push({'index':i, 'param':param2}) ;
    }) ;
}
```

In this example, I suppose to obtain an array in the `$scope.outputData` with data similar to this:

```
[
  {'index':0,param:'a'},
  {'index':1,param:'b'},
  {'index':2,param:'c'},
  {'index':3,param:'d'},
  {'index':4,param:'e'},
]
```

but what i get is data like this:

```
[
  {'index':4,param:'a'},
  {'index':4,param:'b'},
  {'index':4,param:'c'},
  {'index':4,param:'d'},
  {'index':4,param:'e'},
]
```

In this case, the externel data that I mean is the variable `i`,

Please could you tell me the trouble ? and how do I proceed to attend my goal? Thank you in advance and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a closure over the `i` variable to make sure it still has the value you want it to have when you use it.

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    (function(counter) {
        var url = generate_url(i);
        $http.get(url).then(function(response){
            var param2 = response.data.param2
            $scope.outputData.push({'index':counter, 'param':param2}) ;
        });
    }(i));
}
```

But if the ordering of the resulting array matters, you will have to create a temporary array and then sort it on `index`.

You can use `$q.all` if you don't want to process any of the requests untill they have alle completed.

Something like this:

```
var promises = {};
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var url = generate_url(i) ;
    promises[i] = $http.get(url);
}
$q.all(promises).then(function(result) {
  for (index in result) {
      var param2 = result[index].data.param2
      $scope.outputData.push({'index':index, 'param':param2}) ;
  }
});
```

That should also preserve the ordering.

The docs for `$q` are [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).

Comment: that's the right answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a closure issue, the correct way to do it would be

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
   getData(i);
}
var getData=function(index) {
     var url = generate_url(index) ;
    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        var param2 = response.data.param2
        $scope.outputData.push({'index':index, 'param':param2}) ;
    }) ;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works for me too, but the result order is not correct but this is not a problem. Thank you.